# Execution order of expressions in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, order-of-execution

I want to know if the execution order of expressions in `SELECT` statement always takes place from **left to right**.

```
SET @a := 0;

SELECT 
@a AS first,
@a := @a + 1 AS second,
@a := @a + 1 AS third,
@a := @a + 1 AS fourth,
@a := @a + 1 AS fifth,
@a := @a + 1 AS sixth;
```

Is it guaranteed that the above query will always generate the following output?

```
first second third fourth fifth sixth 
  0     1      2     3     4      5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [**`MySQL manual`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
>   variables is undefined

So the answer to your question, is no, the execution order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Giorgos. probably my next question is going to be **Why the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined?** :-/

Comment: @AnonymousOne You have to ask the MySQL dev guys for this one. But, what is your *actual* problem?

Comment: Actually the problem is I've some running queries in some applications which involves `mysql` user variables. Since the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined so that I am too concerned for that. :(

Comment: Giorgos, Can I ask this question in `SO`?

Comment: @AnonymousOne Yes, I think you can.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos. SO won't let me post. Since the gap between two consecutive posts should differ by at least 90 minutes :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by any means there is no configuration for execution order, so you always get output like this.

Comment: Could you please provide any link ? I want to know more/ in details.

Comment: Please look at  Giorgos' answer.