# The execution order for the 'order by' clause in MySQL when user-defined variables exist

Tags: mysql, sql

A question came up to me when I was trying to go through a question in Leetcode(https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores/#/description).

One of the solution for this question is shown below:

```
SELECT
  Score,
  @rank := @rank + (@prev <> (@prev := Score)) Rank
FROM
  Scores,
  (SELECT @rank := 0, @prev := -1) init
ORDER BY Score desc
```

I once read an artical saying that the ORDER BY clause always runs at last and obviously after the SELECT clause. Though I find in this code block it does not. When the order by clause is deleted or changed, the result changes(not the order). I guess it maybe because there are some user-defined variables here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution order of expressions in SELECT statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919532/execution-order-of-expressions-in-select-statement)

Comment: That's more or less true for the order of the clauses (LIMIT is after ORDER BY though). But the order of evaluation of variables is not defined.

Comment: By inference, you already know the answer to this

Answer (score 0):

According the manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), **In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client.** The **Score column** in both select clause and order clause  is certain, but the user defined variables after **Score column** will be evaluated when mysql server send it to the client.